# Pandas read_csv hangs the code without an error, but only sometimes

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a .csv file, with 29 columns.

If I simply use:

`df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')`

then the code just kind of hangs and doesn't do anything. There's no error message at all---it just stops working, or looks like its running and running forever.

But if I use:

`df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', usecols = [0,2])`

or whatever, it works just fine and creates a dataframe with just those columns.

So then I tried:
`df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', usecols = [i for i in range(0,29)])`

But it just hangs the code again.

BUT if I try:
`df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', usecols = [i for i in range(0,23)])`

so that it doesn't read the whole .csv, just the first 23 columns, it works fine. It also works fine for any number from 0 to 23 (like [i for i in range(0,10)] or [i for i in range(0,22)], but NOT for anything greater than or equal to 24.

I also tried doing it the other way around, indexing from the back:
`df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', usecols = [i for i in range(2,29)])`
If I do it this way, it works all the way from column 28 to column 2. But it breaks the code again if I try to go further to column 1 or column 0.

I'm at a loss as to what is happening here. I also do not have a degree in computer science, so please speak to me like someone who taught themselves to code in Python, but very poorly (because I did).

EDIT:

Okay, it looks like I figured it out. Some of the columns had strings in their rows, and some had floats. I guess that was causing some problems, but inconsistently. I'm not really sure what problems, exactly. But it seems to work fine now.

Comment: That was good debug work. How taught means less than putting in the effort! Have you tried reading with the `csv` module? I'd look at those last columns. In fact, using the csv module to isolate those odd columns one by one into separate files then trying pandas on them would be interesting. If you could narrow down to a few rows and columns that still fail, you could post it here.

Comment: Also, hangs or raises exception? If you aren't running on the command line or if you suppressed all exceptions further up, you may not have noticed what the error was.

Comment: Weird. Did you try splitting the file in two? That is, if it is 100 lines long, make it two 50 lines long files. My guess is that there is an errand separator in one of the fields, probably in field 24. You can check for that as well. If your separator is a comma for example and you expect every line to have 28, try something like this awk -F,  'NF>28{print "Error at line "NR;exit}' filename.csv